# RStudio - selected code to snippet - updating r.snippets programmatically

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I like using the RStudio snippets.

I thought it would be great, if i can select code and add it to the snippets by keyboard shortcut.

[So i started working on it.](https://github.com/Timag/Selected_Code_To_Snippet)

[image]

Even if I edit the r.snippets file programmatically, the created snippet seems only to be updated if the r.snippets file will be opened afterwards (in RStudio). As a workaround i call file.edit("~/.R/snippets/r.snippets") at the end of the code.

**My question:**

- Does the file have to be opened or can the changes be recognised by
  RStudio in another way as well?

**Alternative:**
It might be better practise to directly paste the selected code in the r.snippets file for the user(?)

Also asked here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-selected-code-to-snippet-updating-r-snippets-programmatically/20611